# Cascade changes in Mongodb in Django

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, pymongo

Is there a way to change a element of collection in Mongoose and be cascade changed in other collection that points this element, similar to using MySQLs foreign keys?

For example, in MySQL I'd assign a foreign key and set it to cascade on change or delete. Thus, if I were to delete or change name of a activity_Type, all applications and associated activity_Types would be removed or affected as well.

```
class ValuesHelper(object):


    NAME = 'activityType'

    def __init__(self, neo_on=False):
        self.client = MongoClient(settings.DATABASES['mongo']['HOST'],settings.DATABASES['mongo']['PORT'])
        self.db = self.client[settings.DATABASES['mongo']['NAME']]
```

Comment: Are you taking about [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) the object modeling for Node.js, or just MongoDB?

Comment: just MongoDB! i use Backbone framework in my view too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no support for cascade changes at the moment.
(Take a look at this [jira ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1298))

So you need to implement that behavior in your application. For example, if you were using Mongoose, you can do it using its `remove` Middleware. Take a look at JohnnyHK's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14349259/618935) from another SO question for an example.