# How to cascade delete using Mongoose remove middleware?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to delete all dependencies of a schema when a DELETE request is sent to my API. Deleting goes ok, but the remove middleware, which is supposed to clean the dependencies, seems like is not even getting called.

This is my Customer schema:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var Order = require('./order');
var Customer = new Schema({
    name: String,
    telephone: Number,
    address: String,
    email: String,
    seller: String
});

Customer.post('remove', function(next) {
    Order.remove({ customer: this._id }).exec();
    next();
});

Customer.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Customer", Customer);
```

And this is my customer route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var isAuthenticated = require('./isAuthenticated');
var Customer = require('../models/customer');
var Order = require('../models/order');

// (...)

router.delete('/:customer_id', function(req, res) {
    Customer.remove({ _id: req.params.customer_id }, function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.json({ SERVER_RESPONSE: 0, SERVER_MESSAGE: "Error deleting", ERR: err });
        else res.json({ SERVER_RESPONSE: 1, SERVER_MESSAGE: "Customer deleted" });
    });
});

// (...)
```

I did look [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348516/cascade-style-delete-in-mongoose) and Mongoose Docs ([Mongoose Middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)) but it's still unclear to me. I don't know what I'm missing or doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

This is [my project's repository](https://github.com/alexhzr/BilltasticJS). Please, feel free to look into.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this. Middleware wasn't firing because you must use `remove()`, `save()`, etc on model instances, not the model itself.

Example:

`Customer.remove({...});` won't work.

```
Customer.findOne({...}, function(err, customer) {
  customer.remove();
});
```

will work and will do whatever is in `Customer.post('remove')`.

Comment: When I do this, it removes ALL the documents from the collection. In this case, the "Customer" collection. Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't that what you want to?

Comment: No, its meant to remove only ONE instance of "Customer", hence the use of "findOne". But it deletes ALL customer documents on the collection

Comment: Hmmm... Ok, I know what you mean. I was wrong with my last comment. If you do `Customer.findOne()` and use the right filter, it should return only one document, which would be the only one that matches your filter. Here -> https://github.com/alexhzr/BilltasticJS/blob/master/routes/customer.js#L90-L101 I'm filtering by some params, then, when ONE is found, the middleware is fired -> https://github.com/alexhzr/BilltasticJS/blob/master/models/Customer.js#L14-L16

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is the part you're focusing on:

```
Customer.post('remove', function(next) {
    Order.remove({ customer: this._id }).exec();
    next();
});
```

What you're doing wrong here is that the `post` hook is not given any flow control, so the `next` parameter is not actually a function but the document itself.

Change it up to this and you should get what you want:

```
Customer.post('remove', function(doc) {
    Order.remove({ customer: doc._id }).exec();
});
```

From the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post):

> post middleware are executed after the hooked method and all of its
>   pre middleware have completed. **post middleware do not directly receive
>   flow control, e.g. no next or done callbacks are passed to it**. post
>   hooks are a way to register traditional event listeners for these
>   methods.

Comment: I've tried what you said but I still get no results... I've also added `console.log(doc);` to see if it reaches the function, but it didn't.

Comment: It's probably that the function does not execute at all. Make sure that you're actually deleting a customer in the `DELETE` request. What version of `mongoose` do you have?

Comment: I have Mongoose 4.0.2. The DELETE request goes all ok; customer is deleted, but middleware doesn't work.

Comment: Could you try with a `Schema.pre('remove', fn);` instead? That way we can rule out if the `post`-hook is broken in your version. According to the [History.md](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/History.md) they fixed something with the `post` hook in 4.0.3 - although it wasn't clear what they fixed. `fixed; sync post hooks now properly called after function`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is `fn`. A function?

Comment: Yes... Basically what I want you to do is: `Customer.pre('remove', function (doc) { // Other stuff here });`

Comment: And is the function even being executed? `console.log('executed');`

Comment: Nope, no logs on console.

This is the console output: [link](http://i.imgur.com/FNR9nyk.png)

Comment: Well something's clearly misconfigured. Mongoose acts like it's a schemaless collection without any methods for some reason...

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! I've added the link to my project, if it helps.