# Correct way to use array of sub documents in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm just learning Mongoose, and I have modeled `Parent` and `Child` documents as follows..

```
var parent = new Schema({
    children: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Child' }],
});

var Parent = db.model('Parent', parent);

var child = new Schema({
    _owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Parent' }, 
});

var Child = db.model('Child', child);
```

When I remove the `Parent` I want to also remove all the `Child` objects referenced in the `children` field. [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348516/cascade-style-delete-in-mongoose) on Stackoverflow states that the parent's `pre` middleware function can be written like this...

```
parent.pre('remove', function(next) {
  Child.remove({_owner: this._id}).exec();
  next();
});
```

Which should ensure that all child objects are deleted. In this case, however, is there any reason to have the `children` array in the `Parent` schema? Couldn't I also perform create/read/update/delete operations without it? For example, if I want all children I could do?

```
Child.find({_owner: user._id}).exec(function(err, results) { ... };
```

All examples I've seen of Mongoose 'hasMany' relations feature a 'children' array though but don't show how it is then used. Can someone provide an example or give a purpose for having it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are defining two different collections, Child and Parent in ->

`var Parent = db.model('Parent', parent);`

`var Child = db.model('Child', child);`

So you are free to user the Child model as you like by doing add/remove/update. By saving it as a 'ref' you can do:

```
Parent.find({_id:'idofparent'})
.populate('children')
.exec((err, result) => { .... } )
```

Your Parent will then be populated with their children.!

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand, by keeping the refs in an array I can retrieve them by calling `populate` rather than retrieving each child with a query on the child model. But other than that, there's no reason to maintain a child array..

Comment: Yep, populate does those queries for you so very convenient if you want to retrieve a parents all children :)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the clarification