# How do you remove the related object from a mongoose document array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

**Company collection:**

```
{
  "_id": {
      "$oid": "594196a685d5c72f00517f64"
  },
  "name": "company",
  "reports": [
      {
          "$oid": "5942afb5314f0235d9a3a302"
      },
      {
          "$oid": "5942b1641b10b236075bcd89"
      }
  ],
}
```

I understand I have to use update $pull to remove an element from reports.

**How would create the query to achieve this?**

I have this so far,

```
 var Company = require('../models/company');
 Company.update(
   { _id: company},
   { $pull: {'reports': report._id} }
 )
```

**Is there a way to remove reports from this company automatically if I delete a report?**

For example, instead of having to use `update()` on Company after a report is deleted, it would be nice if I can just do `remove()` on a report and Company should know it was deleted. (I come from a rails background so this is annoying)

Comment: Are you using Mongoose? If so, what you're looking for is a [cascade delete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14349259/1022914). My only concern is the way you store your report references. Why is it an array of objects opposed to an array of `ObjectIds`? The latter makes it easier to pull.

Comment: @Mikey I am storing them in `ObjectIds` this is just how mLabs display them. Thanks! cascade delete is exactly what I was looking for @OmriLuzon but I'm using express and angular :( LOL sorry.

Comment: @EricChu Take note that if you set a `'remove'` hook, it will be fired when you call `myDoc.remove()`, not when you call `MyModel.remove(query, callback)`.