# mongoose - Delete all referenced objects when deleting referencing object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-deleteone

### I have two collections in my app. (Table and Buckets)

Table collection

[image]
[image]

Bucket collection

[image]
[image]

---

Here each one site has many buckets. I want to delete all buckets and data using site id (site field in table collection)

If it's duplicated, feel free to close this question, but I didn't find the answer after googling, stack overflowing and in the related topics.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this solve your problem [Cascade style delete in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14349259/3710490)?