# How to delete all the reference of id in mongoose nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

**shopSchema**

```
const shopSchema = new Schema({
  shopName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  foodId: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Food',
  }]
});
```

**foodSchema**

```
const foodSchema = new Schema({
  foodName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  price: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  shopName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  shopId:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Shop',
    required: true
  }

});
```

In this if i delete the food from foodschema how to delete the foodid referenced in shopschema

```
    exports.postdelfood=(req,res,next)=>{
  const fid=req.params.foodId;
  console.log(fid);
  return Food.deleteOne({_id:fid})
  .then(result=>{
    console.log('deleted');
    res.status(200).json({message:'success'});
  })
  .catch(err=>{
    res.status(500).json({message:'failed'});
  })

};
```

is there any function in mongoose to delete all the reference id if we delete anyone of the id?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cascade style delete in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348516/cascade-style-delete-in-mongoose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exports.postdelfood=(req,res,next)=>{
  const fid=req.params.foodId;
  const sid=req.params.shopId;

  return Food.deleteOne({_id:fid})
  .then(result=>{
    console.log(fid);
    Shop.update({_id:sid},{ $pull: { foodId: fid }})
    .then(resu=>{
      console.log(resu);
        console.log('deleted');
      res.status(200).json({message:'success'});

      });    
  })
  .catch(err=>{
    res.status(500).json({message:'failed'});
  });

};
```

I got the answer but is there any any function in mongoose to delete all the reference id if we delete anyone of the id?

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand if your a trying to delete the whole record just use

```
Shop.deleteMany({foodID:fid})
```

if you are trying to just delete the foodID param from the record just set it to NULL 
with

```
Shop.updateMany({foodID:fid},{foodID:null})
```

Comment: in shopSchema there is a array of foodId. How to delete the particular food id from shopSchema.foodId. I have already tried your answer, it's not working, Thank you for the early response