# How to delete all fields in child schema having same parent id when parent is deleted

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on appointment booking app in nodejs

I have 2 schemas one is slot schema which stores the slots (startTime-endTime) and one subSlot Schema which stores the chunks of (StartTime-endTime)

for ex - (10 - 12) is slot range then subslot contains
subSlot - (10:00,10:30,11:00,11:30,12;00)

I want to write a login where if we delete slot all its subslot gets deleted automatically

here what i have tried so far but its not working at all. .remove function is throwing error

```
router.get("/deleteSlot/:id", (req, res) => {
  slot.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err, doc) => {
    if (!err) {
      subSlotBooking.find({ slots: req.params.id }, (err, docs) => {
        if (!err) {
          docs.remove((err) => {
            if (!err) {
              console.log("docs eleted successfully");
            }
          });
        }
      });
      res.redirect("/displaySlot");
    } else {
      req.flash("error_msg", "Failed to delete");
    }
  });
});
```

here is my subslot schemas

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const slotBookingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  startTime: [{ type: String }],
  endtime: { type: String },
  isBooked: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  isDisabled: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  createdBy: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  slots: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "slot" },
});

const subSlotBooking = mongoose.model("subSlotBooking", slotBookingSchema);
module.exports = subSlotBooking;
```

main slot schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { mongo } = require("mongoose");
const subSlotBooking = require("../models/slotBooking.model");

const slotSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    createdBy: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    docdetail: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Doctor",
    },
   startTime: {
      type: String,
    },
    endtime: {
      type: String,
    },
    interval: {
      type: String,
    },
 
  },
  { timestamps: {} }
);
slotSchema.pre("remove", function (next) {
  // 'this' is the client being removed. Provide callbacks here if you want
  // to be notified of the calls' result.
  subSlotBooking.remove({ slots: this._id }).exec();
  next();
});
const slot = mongoose.model("slot", slotSchema);

module.exports = slot;
```

I also tried the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14349259/13489699)

but not working.

How do I do this?

Comment: "but not working." how?

Comment: it throws subSlotBooking.remove is not function error

Comment: and for the logic implemented from another answer in slot schema...it does not delete child items

Comment: Update your question with this information. Debugging requests must include all relevant error output or description of other unexpected behavior.

Comment: Don't wait--update this question.

Answer (score 0):

below code worked for me.
instead of model.remove() use model.deleteMany() if you want to delete multiple child records having same parent id

```
router.get("/deleteSlot/:id", (req, res) => {
  slot.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err, doc) => {
    if (!err) {
      subSlotBooking.deleteMany({ slots: req.params.id }, (err, docs) => {
        if (!err) {
          console.log("docs eleted successfully");
        }
      });

      res.redirect("/displaySlot");
    } else {
      req.flash("error_msg", "Failed to delete");
    }
  });
});
```