# mongodb: Deleting a user and all data references associated with it

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

Currently working on a personal website for myself and ran in to some difficulties with mongodb & mongoose when trying to delete a user.

Right now I have two Schema's show below.

**UserSchema:**

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type:String,
        required: true,
        unique: true, 
    },
    password: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    eMail: String,
    status: {type:Boolean, default: true},
    hobbies: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Hobby"
        }
    ]
```

**HobbySchema:**

```
const hobbySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    user: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
            },
        username: String
    },
  
    desc: String,
    iconURL: String
    
});
```

My issue right now is that when I delete the user using the following route with nodeJS:

```
 router.delete('/delete/:id', async (req,res) => {
    await User.findOneAndDelete(req.params.id, (err, foundUser) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            res.redirect("/logout"); 
        }
    })
});
```

I run into the issue that the Hobby collection still contains **all hobbies that the user created**. I'm looking to have them all deleted when the user wants to delete their account.I understand that Mongodb/Mongoose is a non-relation database and is unlike SQL as I'm coming from SQL. Is there any way to delete all hobbies a user created? (Just creating hobbies as a very basic example).

What is the best alternative? Just going with SQL lite and changing the database entirely?

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348516/cascade-style-delete-in-mongoose

Comment: It requires multiple queries on mongodb if you are using multiple collections. At least one to delet e the hobbies, one to delete the user.