# MongoDB What happens to documents with ObjectId when the document is deleted

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Say I have two models, a `Team` and a `Player`, the `Player` has an ObjectId field that stores a `Team`'s id. If I were to delete a `Team`, would all the `Player`s storing the object Id field become null, or would I manually have to make it null.

Comment: You'd need to manually make them null. There's no concept of foreign keys in mongo.

Comment: mongoose does support cascade delete, but native mongodb does not. Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348516/cascade-style-delete-in-mongoose