# Cascade mongoose implement rollback when having errors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-middleware

I am implement cascade like for mongodb using `pre` remove middleware of mongoose follow : [Cascade style delete in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348516/cascade-style-delete-in-mongoose)

But I when having errors it not rollback deleted data. So how can we start transaction in `pre` middleware and pass it to handler where item trigger middleware is remove and commit changes