# How can I delete cascade documents in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection called **Category** with data structure defined like that:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  parent: null // ref to Category model
},
{
  _id: 2,
  parent: 1
},
{
  _id: 3,
  parent: 2
}
```

Now, I want to delete the document at **_id: 1** and want to make sure its children have also deleted, means the document with **_id: 2** will be deleted because its parent is the document with **_id = 1** and the **_id: 3** with **parent id is 2** will be also deleted.
Keep going like this until we have no related documents.

Do you have any suggestions or documents that I can refer to? Many thanks!

I don't have much experience in mongoose, I tried with recursive solution but I don't think it's a good way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try  'pre' remove middleware

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre

---

And look to answer here
[Cascade style delete in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348516/cascade-style-delete-in-mongoose)